# How do I do a resumable upload to a shared folder in Python using Google Drive API v3?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload files to Google Drive using the Google Drive API v3 and Python 3.10.4. I'm attempting to do a resumable upload. I successfully get the URI location of where to start uploading to but when I attempt to upload the file to the location I get a 404 back from Google.

reason: 'notFound',
message: 'File not found: #FileIdHere',
locationType: 'parameter',
location: 'fileId'

Google gives me the fileId of the folder I'm attempting to upload to. Its the same id I get from my get_folderId function.

```
def backup(drive: Drive, cam_name: str):
    logger.info('Backup drive has been plugged in')
    logger.info(f'Backing up {drive.letter}')

    #Grab the folder ID of the folder we are uploading files to
    folderId = get_folderId(cam_name)
    access_token = get_access_token()

    rootDirectory = drive.letter + "\\FILE\\"
    if not os.path.isdir(rootDirectory):
        rootDirectory = drive.letter + "\\DCIM"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDirectory):
        for fileName in files:
            #Get file path
            filePath = os.path.join(root, fileName)

            #Grab mimetype for file
            mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
            mimeType = mime.from_file(filePath)

            #Get size of file
            fileSize = os.path.getsize(filePath)

            #Retrieve session for resumable upload
            headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer "+access_token, "Content-Type": "application/json"}
            parameters = {
                "name": fileName,
                "mimeType": mimeType,
                "parents" : [folderId]
                
            }
            response = requests.post(
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
                    headers=headers,
                    data=json.dumps(parameters)
            )
            #Location to upload file
            uploadLocation = response.headers['Location']

            #Upload the file
            headers = {"Content-Range": "bytes 0-" + str(fileSize - 1) + "/" + str(fileSize)}
            response = requests.put(
                uploadLocation,
                headers = headers,
                data=open(filePath, 'rb')
            )
            logger.info(response.text)
```

In the parameters variable in the above function, I've tried adding in supportsAllDrives = True to no avail so I'm not sure why its not able to find the folder.

```
#Gets the folder ID of the provided folder name from Google Drive
def get_folderId(cam_name: str):
    service = get_google_service()
    page_token = None
    queryString = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='{}' and trashed = false".format(cam_name)
    response = service.files().list(q = queryString,
                                    spaces='drive',
                                    corpora='drive',
                                    supportsAllDrives=True,
                                    includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
                                    driveId= #DriveIdGoesHere,
                                    fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                    pageToken=page_token).execute()
    folderId = response.get('files')[0].get('id')
    return folderId
```

```
#Gets the Google service
def get_google_service():
        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service.json'
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
                SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
        creds = credentials.with_subject(#EmailGoesHere)
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        return service
```

Comment: In your title, you say `How do I do a resumable upload to a shared folder in Python using Google Drive API v3?`. In this case, do you want to upload a file to a shared folder? In your question and script, I thought that you might want to upload a file to a folder in a shared Drive. So, I'm confusing your current situation. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From `How do I do a resumable upload to a shared folder in Python using Google Drive API v3?`, I thought that you might have wanted to upload a file to a shared folder in Google Drive.
- From your showing script, it seems that you are using the service account.
- But, from `Google gives me the fileId of the folder I'm attempting to upload to. Its the same id I get from my get_folderId function.`, in your situation, I thought that you might have wanted to upload a file to a folder in a shared Drive.

If my understanding is correct, from your error message of `reason: 'notFound', message: 'File not found: #FileIdHere', locationType: 'parameter', location: 'fileId'`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
response = requests.post(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
        headers=headers,
        data=json.dumps(parameters)
)
```

#### To:

```
response = requests.post(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&supportsAllDrives=true",
        headers=headers,
        data=json.dumps(parameters)
)
```

- When you want to upload a file to a folder in a shared Drive and the value of `folderId` is the folder ID of the folder in a shared Drive, it is required to include `supportsAllDrives=true` to the query parameter.

#### Note:

- When I tested your script using your endpoint of `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable`, I confirmed that the same error of `File not found:`.
- When I tested your script using my modified endpoint of `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&supportsAllDrives=true`, I confirmed that the file could be correctly uploaded.
- But, if your service account has no write permission to the shared Drive, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

Comment: I was including supportsAllDrives=true in the wrong location. That was what I was missing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Chase T Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this snippet helps

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as pyImage
from PIL import Image
import progressbar
import requests

def upload_as_csv(df, ver):

   title = "doc-{fver}.csv".format(fver=ver)

   path = 'output/{ftit}'.format(ftit=title)

   df.to_csv(path)

   gauth = GoogleAuth()
   drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

   uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'title': title})
   uploaded.SetContentFile(path)
   uploaded.Upload()
   print('Uploaded file with ID {}'.format(uploaded.get('id')))
   print('Version number {}'.format(ver))

   return True
```